# Change the authentication type in Liferay portal 6

Tags: authentication, liferay-6

I am new to Liferay portal.We have planned to use the version 6.As you know current we can login to Liferay with any of emailAddress,screenName,userId.

1.Our existing Jboss portal is using Customer ID as the user name.So we don't want to change this for liferay portal also.How to include Customer ID as one of the authentication type?

2.In current Liferay portal we can use any one of emailAddress,screenName,userId as the 
user name.Is it possible to use the combination say emailAddress and screenName and password ?

Thanks in Advance.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

See *Authentication: General Settings* at http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/global-server-settin-4. The bottom line is that, out of the box, that Liferay supports 3 **exclusive** authentication mechanisms: a) email, b) screen name, c)User Id. The  email MUST be formated as an email; the screen name CANNOT be formated as an email.

You might also consider AutoLogin, http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Developing+a+Custom+Authentication+System